# MII inpedance matching for LAN9313i

Tags: pcb-design, ethernet, mii

I am designing an ethernet switch using the LAN9313i and the ADIN1100.
For my understanding MII traces should be routed to match 50 Ω.

However, Microchip recommends 68 Ω in their routing checklist and their reference schematic. I can't find any matching resistors. So my understanding is that the chip has internal matching resistors. Analog Devices, on the other hand, has matching resistors in their reference schematic. So thinking that these are the matching resistors to match 50 Ω.

But if I use 68 Ω traces they are getting very thick and the distance is only 2 cm. I wonder if all that is necessary for such a small distance, and if I really need matching resistors.

https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/LAN9313I_XVTQFP_Rev_B_Routing_Checklist.pdf

https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/9313sch.pdf

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adin1100.pdf

https://www.analog.com/en/products/adin1100.html#product-overview

[image]

Comment: 68 ohm traces should be thinner than 50 ohm traces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But if I use 68 Ω traces they are getting very thick and the distance
> is only 2 cm. I wonder if all that is necessary for such a small
> distance, and if I really need matching resistors.

Looks like you are using 10-BaseT (10MHz) at 10MHz PCB effects wouldn't be critical as a wavelength would be 100's of cm (through air). If you are using 10-baseT, it wouldn't even be worth it to do length matching.

Even at 100MHz a wavelength would be 166cm on fr4. So I wouldn't worry about it.

I would probably route the signals as best you can. Shouldn't need any matching resistors (the last design I did with a 100BaseT switch did not need them).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I need any length matching? (The longest trace is 3centimeters long and the shortest is 1 centimeter.)

Comment: Probably not, AFAIK length matching is 20mil on 1000BaseT, so 100BaseT is going to be a lot lower than that (let's just say 200mil for a rough cut number, which will be 0.5cm). I don't think 10BaseT even has skew requirements